# Hyphenation exception list items with underscore?

Tags: pdftex, hyphenation

As a followup to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497206/3925), I'd like to ask: **how to properly add *hyphenation exceptions* that contain underscores?**

**NB:** Previous questions (and I found a few) settled with *somehow* fixing the hyphenation, even if it meant mutilating each and every instance of the word(s) to be hyphenated. But I need a solution that doesn't require me to (from the view of the LaTeX engine) pre-process the text before handing it to LaTeX. Also, modifying each and every instance of these seems to violate one of those sermons I've heard when I initially started with LaTeX during my university time: that LaTeX frees you from having to micro-manage details like that and you just type out the text and the document class in tandem with LaTeX will do the rest.

Consider [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498235/3925) by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer), slightly adjusted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand\funcfamily
{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily\ttdefault\selectfont}
\hyphenation{
    An-Obscenely-Long-Function-Name
    Another_Name_With_Under-scores
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\funcref}{mo}{{%
        \funcfamily\hyphenchar\font=130
        \hyperref[#1]{#1(\IfValueTF{#2}{#2}{})}}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    AnObscenelyLongFunctionName AnObscenelyLongFunctionName AnObscenelyLongFunctionName
    AnObscenelyLongFunctionName AnObscenelyLongFunctionName

    foo bar baz \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName}
\end{document}
```

pdfLaTeX chokes on line 11 with:

```
Improper \hyphenation will be flushed. Another_
Improper \hyphenation will be flushed. Another_Name_
Improper \hyphenation will be flushed. Another_Name_With_
```

Initially I thought [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28182/3925) to the question titled "Hyphenation for words with underscore" would help me out, but it doesn't. In fact I tried also with `\usepackage{underscore}`.

It also doesn't make much of a difference whether I use

```
\hyphenation{
    An-Obscenely-Long-Function-Name
    Another_Name_With_Under-scores
}
```

or:

```
\hyphenation{
    An-Obscenely-Long-Function-Name
    Another\_Name\_With\_Under-scores
}
```

(Well, not entirely true, I get more errors on line 11 if I use the latter, but effectively it's the same to me as both fail to work. Also, if I modify the `catcode` both variants behave identically.)

I read the appendix H "Hyphenation" in the TeX-book, but I reckon it doesn't discuss my case since natural languages don't use underscores.

I also tried adjusting the catcode for the underscore to be 11 before defining the hyphenation exceptions (i.e. surrounding the `\hyphenation{}`, inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489791/3925)), but that failed as well.

So how can I define **hyphenation exceptions** for words/names with underscores?

I would prefer to avoid having to "treat" each and every instance of these words/names ([as in this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349499/3925)), which is why I am looking to add them to the hyphenation exceptions.

Comment: You are just specifying a single long word, that way. Also keep in mind that `underscore` *doesn't* make `_` of catcode 11 or 12, but active.

Comment: This all sounds as if you shouldn't use hyphenation but url break, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95104/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer fair enough, although to stay explicit I'd have to define my own command. I actually stumbled over `url` before and had some issue. But I'll revisit this now and possibly ask in a separate question. Still I think it's worthwhile know _if_ it's possible to use underscores in the hyphenation exceptions _and how_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pdflatex hyphenation depends on the lccode of a char. And the catcode should better not be 8 as `\hyphenation` doesn't like this.

You can change the catcode and the lccode, then the hyphenation works. But be aware that you no longer can use your command in the argument of another command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\DeclareRobustCommand\funcfamily
{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily\ttdefault\selectfont}

\catcode`\_=12 \lccode`\_=`\_
\hyphenation{
    An-Obscenely-Long-Function-Name
    Another_Name_With_Under-scores
}
\catcode`\_=8

\NewDocumentCommand{\funcref}{}{%
 \begingroup
 \catcode`\_=12
 \funcrefaux}

\NewDocumentCommand\funcrefaux{mo}{%
 \endgroup 
 \funcfamily\hyphenchar\font=130
 \hyperref[#1]{#1(\IfValueTF{#2}{#2}{})}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    AnObscenelyLongFunctionName AnObscenelyLongFunctionName AnObscenelyLongFunctionName
    AnObscenelyLongFunctionName AnObscenelyLongFunctionName

    foo bar baz \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{AnObscenelyLongFunctionName} \funcref{Another_Name_With_Underscores} \funcref{Another_Name_With_Underscores}
    \funcref{Another_Name_With_Underscores}


\end{document}
```

Comment: With _But be aware that you no longer can use your command in the argument of another command._ you're saying that it's _not_ a robust command anymore, right? (`funcref`, that is)

Comment: no, it has to change catcodes and this don't work if they are already frozen.