# hyphenation doesn't work with underscores in word "Improper \hyphenation will be flushed"

Tags: hyphenation

I'm getting the error "Improper \hyphenation will be flushed" `\hyphenation{VC\_-X1\_-Specific\_-SetupProfiling\_-func}`. I think thats because of the underscores and the number 1 which is not a letter. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498602/2388

Comment: Thanks! I still had the problem of the number 1 in the word. As far as I read numbers are not allowed in hyphenations, so I used **\newcommand{\SetupProf}{VC\\_\-X1\\_\-Specific\\_\-SetupProfiling\\_\-func}** to create a new command

Comment: as I wrote: if you can use something in \hyphenation depends on the lccode. The default value of numbers is 0 but you can change it as you can change the value for the underscore.

Comment: Yes thats right. But I think in my case it's probably easier to use a \newcommand. There's a lot of overhead using a \hyphenation